# C# EXE w/ Unmanaged C++ Unicode DLL linking to unmanaged C++ ANSI DLL crash

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unicode, ansi

I have a C# executable which loads in a DLL which is a unicode unmanaged C++ DLL. This unmanaged C++ DLL also links to another DLL, an unmanaged C++ DLL that happens to be ANSI.

When I run my C# executable, the program ends up crashing in the ANSI portion of the DLL calls (I haven't been able to pull the exception yet). However, by simply switching the ANSI DLL to Unicode, everything works except for the fact that there is a third DLL, which is from a SDK from another company, which has an apparent sensitivity to unicode/ANSI so it works best if the calling DLL is in ANSI.

So we have one executable calling functions in only one unmanaged unicode C++ DLL which serves as a wrapper for an unmanaged ANSI C++ DLL which is a wrapper for the final unmanaged DLL which we have no information about.

Switching the two intermediary DLL's to unicode corrects the crashing only to have it fail with the third separate vendor DLL (but not fail catastrophically with an exception, they just output incorrectly). We can't switch the first DLL to ANSI because we use Unicode in our C# application and that's our standard across the board.

I don't understand the sensitivity to a second-order DLL. Can someone shed some light on this for me?

I use this class to dynamically link to the DLL's:

```
static class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

            [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

            [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
        }
```

with delegates similar to:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private delegate int ExampleFunction();
```

and switching the CharSet.Auto to .Ansi or .Unicode has no effect.

with function calls and such:

```
m_pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@strDLLName);
                if (m_pDll == IntPtr.Zero) this.Close();

                IntPtr pAddressForExampleFunction = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(m_pDll, "ExampleFunction");
                if (pAddressForExampleFunction == IntPtr.Zero) this.Close();
m_ExampleFunction = (ExampleFunction)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressForExampleFunction, typeof(ExampleFunction));
```

with function call:

```
m_ExampleFunction();
```

elsewhere in code.

Edit:

As requested, the C++ EXE Counterpart:

In the .h file, defined as a member:

```
ExampleFunction pExampleFunction;
```

with

```
typedef BOOL __declspec(dllimport) (*ExampleFunction)();
```

The pExampleFunction being defined as:

```
pExampleFunction= (ExampleFunction) ::GetProcAddress(m_hDll,"ExampleFunction");
```

using this call, prior:

```
m_hDll = AfxLoadLibrary(m_DllName);
```

Comment: (...) However, by simply switching the ANSI DLL to Unicode, everything
works except for the fact that there is a third DLL, which is from a
SDK from another company, which has an apparent sensitivity to
unicode/ANSI so it works best if the calling DLL is in ANSI. (...)

This statement does not make sense to me... unless this third dll is a COM object that you use via a type library, there is only ONE correct way to pass string parameters to functions from this dll. If you pass the wrong type of string, it will crash as expected.

Comment: Even if this "sensitive" dll exposes ansi and unicode functions (exampleA(LPCSTR val)  vs exampleW(LPCWSTR val)), your "client" dll will still need to chose the right function according to the build configuration.

Comment: For the strict reader: I know I am "abusing" the term "unicode" here... please dont focus on that.

Comment: @yms, you're absolutely right. The condition, however, is that the calling DLL, when ANSI, causes the DLL to work correctly. When it is unicode, it doesn't. There are no string parameters which may be the reason behind no crashes in one versus the other. It is difficult to understand why ANSI/UNICODE has any effect when no strings are actually being passed back and forth..

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the problem happens between two unmanaged dlls because string data transfer between them is inconsistent.

ANSI/Unicode dll flag is a compile-time property. Compiler selects types and functions depending on this flag. `TCHAR` for Unicode compiled as `wchar_t` and for ANSI it's `char`. E.g. such difference could cause out of bound problem if one dll expects to get `wchar_t*` with length in symbols, but actual received value is `char*`. This is Undefined Behavior and could cause application crash.

Also many Win API functions have two versions `xxxW` for Unicode and `xxxA` for ANSI. E.g:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
   #define MessageBox MessageBoxW
#else
   #define MessageBox MessageBoxA
#endif.
```

On C# side [`CharSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b93s42f(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute controls string marshaling and determines how platform invoke finds function names in a DLL. It doesn't affect further string manipulations inside unmanaged C++ dll. Method

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private delegate int ExampleFunction();
```

has no strings to marshal, so `CharSet` doesn't affect it. There can be a difference if you have two implementations of this method on your unmanaged C++ side: `ExampleFunctionA` for ANSI and `ExampleFunctionW` for Unicode.

Comment: I agree that it probably is happening with the string data transfer between the two DLL's. However, There is something else to note: I have a C++ EXE that goes through the ANSI/UNICODE and it works, actually. So there is something C# specific that causes this issue.

Comment: @RootAtShell Updated my answer with more info about `CharSet` attribute. Most probably C++ EXE or C# EXE should have no difference. Anything could happen if you have Undefined Behavior, it could work for C++ EXE Debug, but not in Release, or crash in some unpredictable places.

Comment: While I would agree with that statement, we haven't had any unpredictable behavior occur with the C++ EXE side. Now, I do understand that lack of observable problems doesn't mean there are no problems, but in this case, this has been 2+ years in testing and development, with passing across all our tests. We are just creating a C# counterpart now and suddenly having these issues. It seems very strange that we are going from no problems over 2 years to consistent crashing all the time..

Comment: @RootAtShell Please post the API used by your C++ exe application, together with declarations of the executed native methods.

Comment: Nikita, I added it above. It's dynamically linked as well, almost 1-1 in the C++ side as compared to the C# side.

Comment: @RootAtShell Ohh, `BOOL` is there. Try to marshal it as `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]`

Comment: Trying it right now - but BOOL is just a typedef for "int" - you think that's really a culprit?

Comment: The Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer causes an exception when it is marshalled as I1 (also tried I8 for fun and didn't work either)..

Comment: @RootAtShell Seems nope, size of `int` is same as `BOOL`, so it's not a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126668/discussion-between-nikita-and-rootatshell).